# pyttsx3 Module Error in Python 3.8. How to download pyttsx3?

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I was trying to create a text to speech project in vs code but can't because **pyttsx3** was not working as I was using python 3.8.5

Code -:>

```
import pyttsx3
Text= pyttsx3.init()
speech = input("Say Something : ")
Text.say(speech)
Text.runAndWait()
```

I also Tried to install it but it gave error also after every try
Check Image : https://i.ibb.co/kXp5CQ8/111.png

Comment: if  you're on windows you could use https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/tkinter-interface-for-text-to-speech/ or https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/google-text-to-speech-api-how-to-create-mp3-with-text-in-any-language/

Answer (score 0):

Oh. If your compiler has a terminal, you type

```
pip install pyttsx3
```

I use Atom. On the bottom left, there is a + button that creates a new terminal and that is where you type

```
pip install pyttsx3
```